# return empty array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that returns an array, and is passed to foreach i.e.

```
foreach(function() as $val)
```

Since the array I am returning is declared in a series of if statements, I need to return an empty array if all the if statements are evaluated to false. Is this a correct way to do it?

```
if (isset($arr))
  return $arr;
else 
  return array();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend declaring `$arr = array();` at the very top of the function so you don't have to worry about it.

If you are doing the check immediately before you return, I do *not* recommend `isset`.  The way you are using `foreach` is depending on an array being returned. If `$arr` is set to a number, for example, then it will still validate.  You should also check `is_array()`.  For example:

```
if (isset($arr) && is_array($arr))
    return $arr;
else 
    return array();
```

Or in one line instead:

```
return (isset($arr) && is_array($arr)) ? $arr : array();
```

But, like I said, I recommending declaring the array at the very top instead.  It's easier and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! I initially wanted to declare an empty array at the top, so that is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid complexity, Simply

```
return [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code to

```
return (isset($arr)) ? $arr : [] ;
```

if it is true, `return $arr` else `return empty array`

Answer (score 0):

Best to do it like this:

```php
$arr = []; // declare your array upfront

// do your conditional adding and manipulating here
// if (...) $arr['abc'] = 'ABC';

return $arr; // only one return statement needed because the $arr definitely exists
```